# Does python2.7 support Chinese path?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

The python2.7 do not support Chinese path?

```
File "/Users/denghaibing/Desktop/Test/TestPython/testDemo02/apps/用户首页/ordermanage/api/views.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .serializers import OrderSerializer
  File "/Users/denghaibing/Desktop/Test/TestPython/testDemo02/apps/用户首页/ordermanage/api/serializers.py", line 46
    from 用户后台.产品管理.productmanage.models import (
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In my project:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You see, I use two level Chinese directories to group my apps in my Test project.

but this works in Python3.5, but if use the Python2.7 Interpreter, there will comes the `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` issue. It do not supports Chinese path.

Is there a way to let Python2.7 support Chinese path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `__import__` instead.

```
# same as import 用户后台.产品管理.productmanage.models as product_model
product_model = __import__('用户后台.产品管理.productmanage.models')

# same as from 用户后台.产品管理.productmanage.models import something
something = product_model.something
```

Comment: so, every place related Chinese will replace the `import ` to `__import__`?

Comment: Yup, you can do that. For me I consider it as a work around because python doesn't support it using native import.